# return a char function with random options and local variables

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have created a unit test harness to test my program. I wanted it to be able to randomly test each run but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Here is what I was think but I get stuck on what to do next, any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
int main (void)
{
  int testNumber = 1; //for testing
  char carName[] = "";
  double carCost = 0;

  carName = carChosen (testNumber);
  carCost = assessCost (carName); //assessCost takes in the car name and checks what cost of the car will be (error checking so only certain cars can be chosen)

  return 0;
}
```

"testNumber" would normally be seeded with time to create different number's from 1 - 15, but in this situation it's going to be "1" for testing.

This is next bit that I'm having trouble with. Within this function there would be 15 diffrent car options and it will return one depending on the randomly created number.

```
char carChosen (int randNum)
{
  char carOne[] = "Honda";
  char carTwo[] = "Ford";
  if (randNum == 1)
  {
    return carOne; //local variables, not going to work...
  }
  else if (randNum == 2)
  {
    return carTwo; // Again, these return's are here to better represent what I'm trying to create but failing to do so..
  }
}
```

I understand you cannot return local variables, what can I do instead?

Comment: You set your return value to `char` and you try to return `char[]`. You also need to return something if randNum is different from 1 & 2

Comment: @Robolisk Your C++ code looks like C. If it is indeed C++, just use `std::string` (and drop the `void` in `main(void)`).

Comment: @Biffen It is C++, I'm just starting to familiarize myself with it. I'll look into what those can do for me, thank you

Comment: @Thomas I understand that but I put it there due to the fact that I was stuck and didn't know what else to do to get my point across. There should be something for the else return you're right, I just had it for testing purposes but good practice says I should. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: `char carName[] = ""` is not a C++ string, it's a null-terminated array of characters, consisting of a single character (which is obviously the null character). You can change the contents of this array, but since it is statically allocated as a single-character array, the only thing that you can do with it, is changing that single character (which will obviously make it a non-null-terminated array of characters). To put it simple, you need to read a little more about null-terminated (C-style) strings. Alternatively, if your designated language is indeed C++, then use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
void carChosen (int randNum, char * out)
{
  char carOne[] = "Honda";
  char carTwo[] = "Ford";
  if (randNum == 1)
  {
    strcpy(out, carOne); 
  }
  else if (randNum == 2)
  {
     strcpy(out, carTwo); 
  } //.. handle other cases
}
```

Call like

```
  char carName[MAX_LEN];
  carChosen (testNumber, carName);
```

Also maybe you are better of using `switch` instead of nested `if..else` if you have many conditions to test.

I thought it was C looking at the code, if you use C++, you can just return `std::string` objects from your function without any issues.

Comment: It would then be a void, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Better than a switch, a 2d char array

Comment: This worked brilliantly Giorgi Moniava!! Thank you
@Thomas What do you mean a 2nd char array?.... >.>

Comment: Create an array named `cars`, put your cars in it, and strcpy only `cars[randNum]` @Robolisk

Comment: This is a weak design because there is no checking for buffer overflow (and to do so would be a pain)

Comment: @M.M I am sure OP can assume there can be no car names longer than say 150 characters.

Comment: `void carChosen (int randNum, char *out)
{
     char carS[] = {"Honda", "Ford"} ;
     strcpy(out , cars[randNum - 1]) ;
 }`  using char array as said by thomas

Comment: @M.M I can see what you mean but because this is a unit testing harness I created it will always be in my control

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your code looks like C code.  If you want to use C++, then read up on std::string and use that.

If you want to continue with your approach (which is very much a C-like approach), then you'll need to better understand how C strings work.  Namely, how they are stored in memory and how a `char` is different from a `char *` is different from a `char array[]`.

Putting most of that aside for now, my first guess based upon your example code is that you won't actually be modifying the contents of the string.  You just want the string *for* its contents, but you won't be changing them.  If this is accurate than you can just use regular `char *` variable to hold a pointer to a char string.  You only need one copy of the string hanging around, so you can pass around a pointer to that one copy and everyone can read from that pointer.  A quick way to do this is to just use the string literal directly.

```
const char* carChosen (int randNum)
{
  if (randNum == 1)
  {
    return "Honda";
  }
  else if (randNum == 2)
  {
    return "Ford";
  } 
  else 
  {
    return "Audi";
  }
}
```

Note that we are returning a `const char *`.  The `const` is just indicating that we will not be modifying the string that is pointed to.  We definitely do not want to do that because it points to a string literal (which you are not allowed to modify).  Once you have the `const char *` returned by carChosen, you can pass that along to other functions, e.g. assessCost.